# Laravel - PHPUnit multi step testing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, phpunit

I'm kind of new to the world of unit testing. I want my tests to be as clear, clean and abstracted out as possible. I've got the following class -

```
class PasswordResetTest extends GraphQLTest
{

private static $user;
private $authEndpoint = '/graphql/auth';

protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    if (!self::$user instanceof User) {
        self::$user = factory(User::class)->create(
            ['password' => Hash::make('password')]
        );
    }
}

/**
 * Check our default password was set successfully
 *
 * @test
 */
public function assertDefaultPassword()
{
    // get our user
    $user = User::where('email', self::$user->email)->get();

    // check our password is 'password'
    $this->assertTrue(
        Hash::check('password', self::$user->fresh()->password),
        'Unexpected password'
    );
}

/**
 * Perform a password reset via GraphQL
 *
 * @test
 */
public function requestPasswordResetEmail()
{
    // setup our mail faker
    Mail::fake();

    // make sure nothing has been sent
    Mail::assertNothingSent();

    // set our endpoint
    $this->setGraphQLEndpoint($this->authEndpoint);
    $mutation = 'mutation forgotPassword ($email: String) {
        forgotPassword (email: $email)
    }';

    // make our request
    $result = $this->graphQLRequest($mutation, ['email' => self::$user->email]);

    // assert our response
    $result->assertJson(['data' => ['forgotPassword' => true]]);

    // check our reset was sent...
    Mail::assertSent(
        PasswordResetMail::class,
        function (PasswordResetMail $mail) use (&$reset) {
            $reset = $mail->reset;
            return $mail->hasTo(self::$user->email);
        }
    );

    return $reset;
}

/**
 * If our email was sent, now perform our reset...
 *
 * @depends requestPasswordResetEmail
 * @test
 */
public function performPasswordReset(PasswordReset $reset)
{

    // set our endpoint and create mutation
    $this->setGraphQLEndpoint($this->authEndpoint);
    $mutation = 'mutation resetPassword ($reset: inputResetPassword!) {
        resetPassword (reset: $reset)                     
    }';

    $result = $this->graphQLRequest($mutation, [
        'reset' => [
            'token' => $reset->token,
            'password' => 'newPassword',
            'password_confirmation' => 'newPassword',
        ]
    ]);

    $result->assertGraphQLNoErrors();
    $result->assertJson(['data' => ['resetPassword' => true]]);
}
```

So I want to run my tests in multiple chunks -

- Check the password was actually set against the user
- Request password reset and assert an email was sent
- Perform the password reset and assert our password has been updated

I could run all of these tests within one method but I'd rather split them up into separate tests for readability and testability but I'm running into a couple of problems -

- `setUp()` method gets executed for every test, not the whole class of tests so every test I have a new user, not what I want
- If I use `DatabaseTransactions` - which is what I would ideally like to use, that also resets the database every test so subsequent tests would fail

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do or do I have to write it as one big test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One plausible way of doing this that I've worked out is using the `@depends` phpdoc

```
class PasswordResetTest extends GraphQLTest
{

private static $user;
private $authEndpoint = '/graphql/auth';

/**
 * @test
 */
public function assertDefaultPassword()
{

    // create our user
    self::$user = factory(User::class)->create(
        ['password' => Hash::make('oldPassword')]
    );

    // check we exist on the database
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', ['email' => self::$user->email]);

    // check our password is 'password'
    $this->assertTrue(
        Hash::check('oldPassword', self::$user->password),
        'Unexpected password'
    );
}

/**
 * Perform a password reset via GraphQL
 *
 * @depends assertDefaultPassword
 * @test
 *
 * @param User $user
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function requestPasswordResetEmail()
{
    Mail::fake();

    // make sure nothing has been sent
    Mail::assertNothingSent();

    // set our endpoint
    $this->setGraphQLEndpoint($this->authEndpoint);
    $mutation = 'mutation forgotPassword ($email: String) {
        forgotPassword (email: $email)
    }';

    // make our request
    $result = $this->graphQLRequest($mutation, ['email' => self::$user->email]);

    // assert our response
    $result->assertJson(['data' => ['forgotPassword' => true]]);

    // check our reset was sent...
    Mail::assertSent(
        PasswordResetMail::class,
        function (PasswordResetMail $mail) use (&$reset) {
            $reset = $mail->reset;
            return $mail->hasTo(self::$user->email);
        }
    );

    return $reset;
}

/**
 * If our email was sent, now perform our reset...
 *
 * @depends requestPasswordResetEmail
 * @test
 */
public function performPasswordReset(PasswordReset $reset)
{

    // set our endpoint and create mutation
    $this->setGraphQLEndpoint($this->authEndpoint);
    $mutation = 'mutation resetPassword ($reset: inputResetPassword!) {
        resetPassword (reset: $reset)                     
    }';

    // make request to our reset
    $result = $this->graphQLRequest(
        $mutation, [
            'reset' => [
                'token' => $reset->token,
                'password' => 'newPassword',
                'password_confirmation' => 'newPassword',
            ]
        ]
    );

    $result->assertGraphQLNoErrors();
    $result->assertJson(['data' => ['resetPassword' => true]]);
}

/**
 * After we have performed all of our tests, delete our user...
 */
public static function tearDownAfterClass()
{
    self::$user->forceDelete();
    parent::tearDownAfterClass();
}
```

}

This way I can define my user in the first test, subsequent tests have `@depends` phpdoc which references previous tests, allowing me to setup the user in the first request and access the user in subsequent requests.

I've then used the `tearDownAfterClass` method to remove the created user from the database. I'd be keen to hear other peoples solutions though!